# L4 and Wordpress - How to install L4 on subdomain shared with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, laravel, subdomain

Here is the structure I am aiming for:

```
    project1.site.com  -> laravel projects
    project2.site.com  -> laravel projects
    project3.site.com  -> laravel projects
    www.site.com       -> wordpress install
```

How can I accomplish this?  I currently tried the following web host structure

```
    /home/user/www/wp         -> wordpress install
    /home/user/l4/project1    -> laravel app folders
    /home/user/www/project1   -> laravel public folder
```

However L4 is not loading properly - it cannot access the app folder ("No such file or directory" when trying to access the L4 bootstrap folder located outside the webroot).  I checked the folder permissions and everything looks fine, my guess is wordpress is not playing well with laravel.

Anyone know how to fix this?  Or provide a setup to allow for a wordpress site with separate subdomains for each laravel project?

Answer (score 0):

Try a structure like this:

```
/home/user/www/wp      ->  Wordpress install
/home/user/www         ->  Laravel install
```

Make sure your home page goes to `/home/user/www/public`.

Also, for readability, I recommend calling the Wordpress install folder `blog`.